# spinner working on desktop, but not in iphone

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, spinner

I have a page with this body :

```
<body>
    <div class="loading">
            <div class="loader"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="site-content">
 [... all the content]
</div>
</body>
```

I am using this code to show / hide a spinner

```
<script>
    function unLoader(e) {
    document.querySelector(".site-content").style.display='none';
    document.querySelector(".loading").style.display='block';
    }
     window.onload = function() {
        document.querySelector(".loading").style.display='none';
        document.querySelector(".site-content").style.display='block';
        window.onbeforeunload = unLoader;
    };
</script>
```

The problem is that the spinner works in desktop both PC and mac, on safari, firefox, chrome etc...

But it does not work on my Iphone.

On the other side, i am using the spinner for calls in ajax :

```
var $loading = $('.loading').hide();
$(document)
    .ajaxStart(function () {
        $loading.show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        $loading.hide();
    });
```

But this time the spinner works in mobile device (iphone) !

How can I make the spinner work for the mobile devices in all my pages (using the code shown first) ?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1 :
for testing, I tried this code :

```
<script>
    $(window).on("load", function(){
        $(".loading").show();
        $(".site-content").hide();
    });
</script>
```

And it does indeed show the spinner (and of course does not hide it).

So the probleme is with the `onbeforeunload` event ...

Comment: Well, one inconsistency is that your secondary snippet is not changing the display property of the `.site-content` while your first snippet is.

Comment: When you say 'The spinner is not working', what exactly is going wrong? Is it not displaying, is it failing to revert to the `.site-content` on load? what behaviour are you observing?

Comment: In the first case no spinner is shown on mobile while in second case (ajax call) the spinner is shown on mobile

Comment: the problem now is : why does onbeforeunload not work properly on iphone devices ?